# How to solve $y = \sqrt{k\sqrt{k\sqrt{k \sqrt{k\sqrt{\dots}}}}}$?

Tags: radicals

$\text{Given}\quad y = \sqrt{k\sqrt{k\sqrt{k \sqrt{k\sqrt{\dots}}}}}\quad \text{ where }\,k\geq 0,\;\;\text{find the value of }\,y.$
I have no idea on how to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We know that
$$
y=\sqrt{k\cdot\sqrt{k\cdot\sqrt{\dots}}}
$$
We can square the equation and divide by $k$:
$$
\frac{y^2}k=\sqrt{k\cdot\sqrt{\dots}}
$$
But the right hand side is just $y$ again, so we have
$$
\frac{y^2}k=y
$$
Solving this gives $y=0$ or $y=k$.

Comment: This answer assumes that $y$ exists. One also needs to show that the sequence of iterated square roots converge.

Answer (score 25):

$$y=\sqrt{k\cdot\sqrt{k\cdot\sqrt{\dots}}}=k^{1/2+1/4+1/8+...}=k^{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-1/2}}=k^1=k$$

Comment: That's a nice approach too. I hadn't thought of it that way.